# GraphAPI Creating a new MSTeam right after creating a new group fails with 404

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to form a new MSTeam from a newly created group.

- I created a new GraphServiceClient
- I created a new AuthProvider
- I created a new Group with the client like this:

  graphApplicationClient.groups().buildRequest().post(group);

It works till here. I get a Group object as a response and can work with it. It has an Id and so on

Right after that I want to create a new team out of this group, so I call

```
ITeamRequest iTeamRequest = graphApplicationClient.groups(pGroupId).team().buildRequest();
iTeamRequest.setMaxRetries(3);
iTeamRequest.setDelay(10);
Team newTeam = iTeamRequest.post(team);
```

where pGroupId is the Id I got from the call before.
(In this case: "team" is a new Team-Object created right before this call, like in the MS-Docs.)

I know the sentence from MS-Docs:

> If the group was created less than 15 minutes ago, it's possible for
>   the Create team call to fail with a 404 error code due to replication
>   delays. The recommended pattern is to retry the Create team call three
>   times, with a 10 second delay between calls.

thats why I added the maxRetries and Delay..
I watched this video:

https://youtu.be/ybGm1qWVi-k?t=650

in which two MS Employees do exactly the same as I do...
What am I missing? Or is there a workaround for it?

This is the response:

```
404 : Not Found
Strict-Transport-Security : max-age=31536000
Cache-Control : private
x-ms-ags-diagnostic : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_51"}}
client-request-id : b39c16e4-f786-4d42-865e-9f0cf23ed46f
request-id : 07efc77c-02d3-45f7-85ab-6ca2241d1859
Content-Length : 198
Date : Thu, 23 Apr 2020 12:39:30 GMT
Content-Type : application/json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "07efc77c-02d3-45f7-85ab-6ca2241d1859",
      "date": "2020-04-23T12:39:30"
    }
  }
}
```

It also does not work, if I put more retries (10 = Max) and more Delay (180 = Max) in it...
And there is no PUT in java..

[image: There is no PUT in Java]

Best regards

EDIT1: I tried to get it done with two other options.. first with ScribeJava and second with a normal httpRequest.. none of them works. I only get it done with graphExplorer.. With the other options it says BadRequest, but when i copy everything I got in code to GraphExplorer it works... help me :(

EDIT2: I have a group that's been around for a day. From this I wanted to create a new team. Still 404 Not Found. I tried it with GraphAPI and ScribeJava.. None of these calls are working. Debugged through, copied all information, put it in Postman, works fine.

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have added the access token with the required permissions. Here is a sample code to [create team using Graph API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-sample-adminbot-csharp).

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that I have the right access token, because right before I create a new Azure Group with the same access-Token and it works fine. I get the Group-Object and have access to the group.id method, which provides me the Id of the new Group.. I debugged through and copied the access-token and did a Postman call -> works fine. But not with code.. (In Postman I have to use PUT.. but there is no PUT in Java in the graph-sdk...)

Comment: There is a PUT in java SDK. Could you please try out the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#tabpanel_CeZOj-G++Q_java)

Comment: I added a picture in my question. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who has the same problem as I. GraphAPI provides a customRequest() function.
I use the same token, the same url, the same properties, but using the customRequest with PUT. Works...

```
CustomRequest<JsonObject> createTeamCustomRequest = graphApplicationClient.customRequest("/groups/" + pGroupId + "/team").buildRequest();
createTeamCustomRequest.setMaxRetries(3);
createTeamCustomRequest.setDelay(10);
JsonObject newTeam = _createTeamInJson();
JsonObject createdTeam = createTeamCustomRequest.put(newTeam);
```

This is the _createTeamInJson function. Returns the same body as I create a Team with GraphAPI

```
private JsonObject _createTeamInJson()
  {
    JsonObject teamPayload = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject memberSettings = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject messagingSettings = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject funSettings = new JsonObject();
    memberSettings.addProperty("allowCreateUpdateChannels", true);
    messagingSettings.addProperty("allowUserEditMessages", true);
    messagingSettings.addProperty("allowUserDeleteMessages", true);
    funSettings.addProperty("allowGiphy", true);
    funSettings.addProperty("giphyContentRating", "strict");

    teamPayload.add("memberSettings", memberSettings);
    teamPayload.add("messagingSettings", messagingSettings);
    teamPayload.add("funSettings", funSettings);
    return teamPayload;
  }
```

This isn't the right solution for it, because it should work with the normal GraphAPI, that's why I don't mark this as an answer. But it is a workaround for everyone who has the same problem..